# Parse nodes in a dijit.tree

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

I'm struggling with a dijit.Tree and I can't find what I need in the dojo documentation...

I want to change the style of a few elements in my tree, according to some conditions.

I am able to identify the elements through a combination of for loops and if evaluations :

```
itemList = this.tree.model.store._arrayOfAllItems;
for (var index in itemList) {
    item = itemList[index];
    if (item.<property> == ...) {
       ...
       //This is where I want to change the style
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But then, I fail to get the node id to call dojo.addClass(nodeId, newClass).

Am I parsing through the proper list, with the model.store._arrayOfAllItems?  Is there a way to parse through the node list instead, and still access the data properties?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

**Edit on 2015-11-23**

With Richard's comments, I was able to obtain the result I was looking for.  I have added a handler that connects the tree's onOpen event to a method that gets the open node map (from tree._itemNodesMap) and then fetch through the store.  For every item in the store, it adjust the css if the id of the item being validated has an associated node in the open node map.  It then looks recursively for children.

Thanks Richard for your help!

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to change? It is also possible to modify the nodes as they're being inserted into the tree (or store that backs up the tree).

Comment: I want to change de style for the tree element.  Write some in italic, some in bold, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the id of the node inside the tree, you can use the `getNodesByItem` function that tree has.

Although if your tree is dynamic and the contents can change, I would suggest writing a function that not only adds to your store but also adds to a class for the node formed in the tree.

Comment: That's the problem : I can't find the ID of the node in the tree.  I can't locate that information in the tree object.

Comment: The arrayOfAllItems does return IDs you can use with getNodesByItem. Although, _arrayOfAllItems is considered a private variable so you can always use the `fetch` method instead

Comment: I have updated my code to use the fetch and getNodesByItem methods.  I believe I have to use a recursive function to loop through all the children items in the store.  When I use the getNodesByItem method with an item directly returned from the fetch method, it works.  But when I loop through children, the getNodesByItem method  returns undefined.

Comment: To get the children list, I have tried to ways : 
1- use tree.getChildren(item).  No matter what I provide as the item parameter, it keeps returning the first level of the tree
2- for loop within the item.children attribute.  Looking for the node for one of those children returns undefined

Comment: For dijit trees, it's because the children don't exist until you actually open the node. So you'll actually have to plug in to when a node is opened up and then set the classes then. Either that or you'll have to expand all the nodes and then minimize them after you've set the classes

Comment: I have edited the post with the solution.  Thank you for your help!